# Images in Stack Snippets blog post are broken

Tags: bug, broken-link, blog

[This post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) comes up among the first search results for "stack snippets mobile", and the images therein are missing:

[image: Broken images in stack snippets blog post]

Comment: The links have been correctly updated to `https://i.stack.imgur.com/` though.

Comment: Nothing appears to be wrong with the [markdown of the blog post](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/blob/master/_posts/2014-09-16-introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets.markdown)

Comment: Huh... do all `i.stack.imgur` images redirect to `/wp-content/uploads/`?

Comment: The domain itself is different on the image source. netdna-ssl.com?

Comment: perhaps theres some blocking going for those requests...

Comment: odd. i dont even see network requests for those...

Comment: it seems to interperate them as documents acc. to chrome console

Comment: these are broken: https://zgab33vy595fw5zq-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/kZPXw.png

Comment: `<a href="//i.stack.imgur.com/h6BFu.png"><img src="https://zgab33vy595fw5zq-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/h6BFu.png" alt="The Markdown toolbar with the new Stack Snippet button"></a>` The `href` is correct, but the `src` is broken

Comment: Thanks for the report, forwarded it to the folks managing the blog to [fix it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhy7dXWjpAA).

Comment: @MichaelStum similar issue: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347842/new-protected-question-status-blog-image-link-broken?cb=1