# new-protected-question-status blog image-link broken

Tags: bug, broken-link, blog

https://stackoverflow.blog/images/wordpress/superuser-deleted-answers.png

in the blog post

https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/07/new-protected-question-status/

strangely enough the preview image is still there

the page told me to report that on "our feedback site"

Comment: Similar to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346389/images-in-stack-snippets-blog-post-are-broken